# File upload form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-uploads

I'm trying to create a simple upload form for my project in `Django 1.5` an `Python 2.7`.

This is my `File` class:

```
class File(models.Model):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'

    school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 140, blank=False, null=False)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices = school_choices, default = blank)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default = 0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default = 0, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to= "/file/")
```

this is the form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'

    school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 30, required = True)
    file = forms.FileField()
    description = forms.CharField(max_length = 140, required = False, label='Breif description of the files content')
    school = forms.ChoiceField(choices = school_choices, required=False, label='What level is the material that are you uploading?', initial = blank)
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.order_by('?'), required=False, label='What subject this file is about?')
    price = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

this is the view:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = File(file = request.FILE['file'])
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_file.name = cd['name']
            new_file.description = cd['description']
            new_file.school = cd['school']
            new_file.subject = cd['subject']
            new_file.price = cd['price']
            new_file.rating = '0.0'
            new_file.user = request.user
            new_file.save()
            form = Search()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form, 'request': request})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form, 'request': request})
```

and this is the relative `HTML`

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>You must be logged to upload a file</p>
{% endif %}
```

My app path is: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/` and I want hose files saved in the folder: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/file/`. In my `Setting.py` I set:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/file/'
MEDIA_URL = '/file/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The problem is: when i select the file and hit the upload button the `FileField` empties itself and the form raise an error since that field is required.

I fear I'm doing something wrong with the media/static paths in the `Setting.py` because the view syntax it's the same as the one in the [Django docmentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) but I really don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify `enctype` in `form` tag to allow file upload.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Ok, this solve my problem! Now it raise an error: SuspiciousOpration at /upload/ Attempted access to '\file\test_file.txt' denied.

Problem is, I have aministrator permissions on this pc (Windows 7) so i fear that my static/media path are still messed up.

Comment: @Higure, I have no idea. Search for the error or post another question.